# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: performs animation without animation

Tags: ios, animation, performselector, animatewithduration

I have a method called by `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, which performs animation with duration. So after the delay, animation runs but without animation duration:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animate:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1] afterDelay:4.0];

-(void) animate:(int) mode
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 568.0 + mode*height/2);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Also, I cannot nest animations in `completion:` because it blocks UI interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and animation duration works great but I think you should fix the (int) mode part. You can't cast NSNumber to int that way. Your method must be - (void)animate:(NSNumber*)mode and after you can cast to int with [mode intValue].

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I found my mistake. I was passing wrong mode value (1 instead of -1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with `animate:` because it has a parameter that is not object-pointer type.

Comment: For some reason it still worked. Nevertheless, changed it to 
- (void)animate:(NSNumber*)mode

Comment: @user3003787: You are running into undefined behavior. Technically, since `int` and pointers have the same size, what is happening is the pointer to the object is interpreted as an int.